# Split tags from input field ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a input field where a user can insert a comma separated list, then on the save method, it tries to split the string and save into tags table.

When I save the post, I get this in my tags table: (GalleryId is the post its related to)

[image]

Each separated value should go into its own row, but instead, I get that.

This is what I do on the Save method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(Gallery gallery) {

  var tags = gallery.Tags.ToString();

  gallery.Tags = ParseTags(tags);

  _context.Galleries.Add(gallery);

  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

  return RedirectToAction("UploadForm", "Gallery");
}


public List<Tag> ParseTags(string tags)
{
    return tags.Split(",").Select(tag => new Tag
    {
        Name = tag
    }).ToList();
}
```

And this is my Gallery Model:

```
namespace SimpleImageGallery.Models
{
  public class Gallery
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }

      public virtual IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }    
  }
```

Tag class:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What can I do to get them to split?

Comment: For a start, `Tags` would need to be a `string`, not `IEnumerable<Tag>`. But storing comma separated values in a db is not good practice - [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: And what is `Tag` anyway? Why do you have a complex object for it when you never use it?

Comment: show the Tag class please

Comment: I added the tag class on the bottom of post

Comment: @David, What you have shown us is not making sense. You have stated the image is for the Tags table, but that class does not contain a property named `GalleryId`. You either have a `Gallery` table, and a `Tags` table and a many-many table (`GalleryTags`)which contains the FK relationships to GalleryId and TagId. Or if you wanting to store a comma separated string (bad practice), then your `Gallery` class needs a `string Tags` property, not a `IEnumerable<Tag> Tags` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, I just had to add the `string tags` into my parameter like this:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Save(Gallery gallery, string tags) {


    if (tags != null)
    {
        gallery.Tags = ParseTags(tags);
    }


    _context.Galleries.Add(gallery);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction("UploadForm", "Gallery");
 }
```

Also, check to see if any tags passed in before handling it.